# Am I right about the differences between can and could?

Tags: grammar

Does “can” mean possibility while “could means probability?

For example,

Example 1

A: I don’t like those statues. They are blocking the gate.

B: Well, they **can** be removed. Most of them weigh only 20 kilograms each. (Moving them is possible or feasible. Whether or not it really happens is not mentioned)

Example 2

A: Mom says those statues are blocking the gate.

B: I know. She is coming back tonight. All of those statues **could** be removed. (The statues will probably be removed. There’s a chance this will really happen)

Is my comparison correct?

Comment: Hi, asking "am I right?" isn't really a question within the scope of the site. There are already countless posts on 'can vs could' - have you tried the search function?

Comment: In this context, I would say that "They could be removed" means "It is theoretically possible to remove them if required".

Answer (score 1):

Broadly:

- "Can" means it is possible, directly. "I can remove the statue right now, if you want!"
- "Could" means that it's possible, with some proviso or condition. e.g. We could remove the statue, IF they removed the concrete barrier first.

Usually, "could" is more doubtful than "can": it means we can do it, but perhaps we must wait until we have permission, or something else is done first.

This is also visible in questions:

1. Do X for me.  (a command, quite rude)
2. Can you do X for me?  (still a command, but polite)
3. Could you do X for me?  (you have more chance to say "no...")

In everyday speech: these aren't questions, they are phatic (telling you to do something, politely).